# How can I create a online collaborative document where I only allow certain users to edit certain sections?

Tags: google-docs, sharing

I want to create a online document that can be shared with many different users but I only want those users to be able to edit and view certain sections.  The hard part is I want it all to feed one document and I want the ability to give different users access to different sections of the document.  My first though was using multiple Google Docs but that fails because I can't feed all those documents up into one (at least that I know of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time is not possible.

**References**
[How to share - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en)